# Finding a Matrix Representing a Linear Transformation with Two Ordered Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question may be a bit off - I'm wondering why the steps for these two problems are different.

Essentially, I'm trying to find a certain matrix *A* that represents a linear transformation *L* with respect to two ordered bases.

In the first question, these bases are $\{ \mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2\}$ and the column vectors of:

$$
\mathbf b = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

The linear transformation $L$ from $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ is:

$$
L(\mathbf x) = x_1\mathbf b_1 + x_2\mathbf b_2 + (x_1+x_2)\mathbf b_3.
$$

I use $L$ to get an initial matrix with respect to the standard basis. Then, apparently, my answer would become
\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\1&1 \end{pmatrix}

In another problem, the given bases are:
$$
\mathbf u = 
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\0&2&1\\-1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf b = 
\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\-1&-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
with a linear transformation given by
$$\
L(\mathbf x) = (x_3, x_1)^T.
$$

We're going from $\mathbb R^3$ into $\mathbb R^2$.

The steps to solve this problem are very similar to the first problem, only you need to perform another computation in that to find the final matrix $A$ you multiply $L(\mathbf u)$ by the inverse of $\mathbf b$ like this:
$$
\mathbf b^{-1}L(\mathbf u) = A.
$$

This makes sense since we're changing the basis. However, why do we not do the same thing for the first problem I mentioned? I tried to do so and obtained the wrong answer. Is it because the matrix would already be in standard representation and thus nothing else needs to be done to it?

Clarification would be very helpful. If anything is unclear, let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by the notations $\ ^*e^*_1$ and $\ ^*b^*_1$? What are the asterick representing?

Comment: Now I understood: he was using markdown. It looks so weird when in LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use italics but I'm still new to using LaTeX. It was working before I had to leave to run a few errands, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the matrix for $L$ with the canonical basis on the codomain is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix},
$$
since 
$$
L\mathbf e_1=L\,\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf b_1+\mathbf b_3
=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
L\mathbf e_2=L\,\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf b_2+\mathbf b_3
=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
And then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\,\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix},
$$
so you are, indeed, also multiplying by $\mathbf{b}^{-1}$.

Comment: Really, nice answer +1

Comment: Could you elaborate on the process of how to obtain that matrix? I'm not sure I understand the terminology.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Oh, excellent. I can see where I went wrong now, my computation was wrong. Thank you for the quick elaboration!

Comment: Glad I could help!